# java script code for preventing user from closing browser without alert messege in chrome

Tags: javascript

This code is giving alert message but I want to prevent user from closing browser. If I comment this line and place alert code before below given code it works, but I want not to show any dialog box.

```
set Interval(function () {alert("**Hello")}, 10);
```

I tried above code but I close browser from current tab also:

```
{
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
    confirmExit();
}
```

Comment: *"but i want not to show any dialog box"* - so don't use `alert`. What are you asking here? Your questions is messy, try explaining yourself better.

Comment: Why are you calling `confirmExit`?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to stop the user closing the window or tab.

Comment: i want user cant close browser easily even he cant see any dialog box or alert messege.

Comment: these code which is written above show dialog box or alert on browser i want user will be unable to see any messege or box

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code..

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Any string';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Any string';
};
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abianjali00/m2oprh37) try this also.....

Comment: can we hide the alert dialog box or something else above code is showing an alert

Comment: Then what is your requirement brother..?? please mentioned that first.. If you dont want alert box, just remove that, if you dont want dialogue box just remove that also.., Then what you want to display..???  Without anything how you will prevent the closing.???

Comment: these code which is written above show dialog box or alert on browser i want user will be unable to see any message or box and user will be unable to close browser

Comment: i have shown my own alert messege to user using alert but user can easily close browser and current tab also .I just want to prevent user from closing current tab and browser

Comment: Abijith Ajayan how much is that compleated?

Comment: Hai Jitender, really sorry dude i didn't find any solution for preventing the browser closing, but we have an option for count the alert box for multiple times, for eg: we  have to set 999 times for closing alert.. after that click only they has to close the browser.

Comment: it is not possible in Mozila firefox because its default popup is blocked. I did it.